# Nginx serves root of one subdomain instead of root of another subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have two subdomains, app.mydomain.com and v1.api.mydomain.com, pointing to the same IP. I want app.mydomain.com to be proxied to localhost:5000 and v1.api.mydomain.com to be proxied to localhost:1337.

The following configuration does it (app.mydomain.com/... is served by localhost:5000 and v1.api.mydomain.com/... is served by localhost:1337) except for one thing: the root of v1.api.mydomain.com (with or without a trailing slash) isn't served by localhost:1337, it is served by localhost:5000 (app.mydomain.com) and therefore it doesn't display what I expect. How is this possible?

My first configuration file in sites-enabled:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name app.mydomain.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
      proxy_set_header Host $host;  
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
  }
```

My second configuration file in site-enabled:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name v1.api.mydomain.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
      proxy_set_header Host $host;  
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
  }
}
```

To make sure that the problem wasn't a redirection of some sort by the server running on localhost:1337, I shut it down and the problem is still there, so it really is something with my nginx configuration. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: I just reopened my Ubuntu session and Chrome browser (I don't know if that clears the cache though), and restarted the nginx server. It is now working. Which one really solved my problem, I couldn't tell, but thanks for the hint.