# One of the subdomains keeps rerouting to another one (sports.example.com -> news.example.com)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

### Problem: a subdomain keeps redirected to another

I'm trying to install a new subdomain **sports**.example.com for my server, and I have another subdomain which is currently working fine at **news**.example.com. Problem is, every time I visit **sports**.example.com, it redirects to **news**.example.com.

### Background

Both domains are wordpress sites, and I can confirm that the new one is indeed "resolved" correctly when I visit **sports**.example.com/*info.php*  if I manually touch and edit a `info.php` file.

Here is the `sports` config file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sports.example.com`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /home/sd/sites/sports.example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name sports.example.com; 

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sports.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sports.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = sports.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name sports.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And here goes the config file for **news** subdomain (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/news.example.com`:

```
server {
        root /home/sd/sites/news.example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name news.example.com; 

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/news.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/news.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = news.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name news.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879764/nginx-serves-root-of-one-subdomain-instead-of-root-of-another-subdomain) closest to may case, but I don't have any proxies whatsoever installed on my system, which bears 2 more subdomains served from the very same VPS with the same IP address. They are some django sites, though, if that matters.

Comment: You have two `server` blocks with the same `listen` and `server_name` values. Test the configuration using `nginx -t`.

Comment: Ah yes, nginx "warns" the conflicting `server_name` on `:80`, but test is successfull in the end:  
```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "sports.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored  
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok  
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful  
```